# Evaluate: $\frac{d}{df}\big( \int_{X} f^{2}(x_{1} - x) dx - 2\int_{X} g(x)f(x_{1} - x)dx \big)$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, derivatives

I want to take the derivative of:

$\frac{d}{df}\big( \int_{X} f^{2}(x_{1} - x) dx - 2\int_{X} g(x)f(x_{1} - x)dx \big)$

Where $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Can I simply write:

$2\int_{X} f(x_{1} - x) dx - 2\int_{X} g(x)dx $

Or is this incorrect?

Comment: What I would do first is to do a change of variable so that you're integrating over $x_1-X$, at which point it is much simpler to see how things should work out.

Comment: Okay so I get $-\int_{X}f^{2}(u)du + 2 \int_{X}g(x_{1} - u)f(u) du$ with $u = x_{1} - x$. So then I should get $-2\int_{X}f(u)du + 2\int_{x}g(x_{1}-u)du$ ?

Comment: I think what you should get is $-2f(x) + 2g(x_1-x)$ or something quite similar to that. Remember that when you compute the derivative, you replace $f$ with $f+\varepsilon\phi$ and do the derivative with respect to $\varepsilon$ and set $\varepsilon$ to zero (like a directional derivative).

Answer (score 1):

Let's set up your functional, call it $F$, then

$$ F[f] = \int_X f(x_1-x)^2\,dx - 2\int_X g(x)f(x_1-x)\,dx.$$

The derivative of $F$ with respect to $f$ is the function $\frac{dF}{df}$ such that

$$\int_X \frac{dF}{df}(x)\phi(x)\,dx = \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}F[f+\varepsilon \phi]\bigg|_{\varepsilon=0}. \tag{1} $$

It's hard to guess what $\frac{dF}{df}$ should be, so let's work with the right hand side to see what we get

$$ F[f+\varepsilon\phi] = \int_X (f(x_1-x)+\varepsilon\phi(x_1-x))^2 - 2\int_X g(x)(f(x_1-x)+\varepsilon\phi(x_1-x))\,dx. $$

Taking a derivative with respect to $\varepsilon$ and subsequently setting $\varepsilon$ to zero gives

$$ \frac{d}{d\varepsilon} F[f+\varepsilon\phi]\bigg|_{\varepsilon=0} = 2\int_X f(x_1-x)\phi(x_1-x)\,dx -2\int_X g(x)\phi(x_1-x)\,dx. $$

We have $\phi(x_1-x)$ in both integrands but based on $(1)$, we need $\phi(x)$. The obvious way to generate $\phi(x_1-x)$ from $\phi(x)$ is to integrate against a Dirac delta, giving

$$ 2\int_X (f(x_1-x)-g(x))\int_{\Bbb R}\delta(x'-x_1+x)\phi(x')\,dx'\,dx. $$

At this point, interchange the two integrals and do some case-by-case breakdowns and you should get your answer. (Hopefully I have not made any errors.)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by $\dfrac{d}{df}$ ?

If you mean the derivative $\dfrac{d}{dx_1}$ with respect to parameter $x_1$, your computation should be:

$2\int_{X} f(x_{1} - x)f'(x_{1} - x) dx - 2\int_{X} g(x)f'(x_{1} - x)dx$

Comment: $\frac{d}{df}$ represents a functional derivative along the lines of variational calculus. It is not meant in a usual sense.

Comment: @CameronWilliams All right, I understand.